# Creation of RSS/XML feed for the ad list on this page

Tags: rss, xml, feed

I'd like to ask the community if they could tell a newbie whether the creation of a feed from the job ad list on this page is generally possible and if there are any pointers where to start?

http://www.oehweb.at/service/jobboerse/

Comment: Are you the author of the site? Or is it just a site you happen to look at?

Comment: No I'm not the author - I'd just like to keep updated. And I thought I might make a feed out of the list and let ifttt or suchlike send me an email if there is a new ad on the list.

Comment: Hmm, I can't think of an easy way without doing a screenscrape yourself..

Comment: BTW, I tried feedity, i.e., but I can't find suited tags..

Comment: I'd give page2rss a shot, though, that tends to pick up *any* changes to the page. Unfortunately, this is a vague enough problem that you may need to try a few iterations before you get something that works.

Comment: tried page2rss without luck..